# insufficient permission google drive api oauth2 in php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file on google drive through PHP. I've created a project in the developer console, enabled the Drive API and added an OAuth 2.0 client ID.
here is my code.

```
<?php
 require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

    session_start();

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        $drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $files_list = $drive_service->files->listFiles(array())->getFiles();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($files_list);
    } else {
        $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/oauth2callback.php';
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }   
    $filename = "abc.txt";
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setName($filename);
    $result = $drive_service->files->create($file, array(
  'data' => file_get_contents("abc.txt"),
  'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
  'uploadType' => 'media'
));
```

Output is:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
' in D:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:118
```

Answer (score -1):

The error means [`The user does not have sufficient permissions for the {fileId}`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_the_user_does_not_have_sufficient_permissions_for_file_fileid) The user does not have write access to a file, and the app is attempting to modify that file.

Grant your service account permission to access the file. Use [`Permissions:insert`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) to inserts a permission for a file.

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.Permission;

import java.io.IOException;
// ...

public class MyClass {

  // ...

  /**
   * Insert a new permission.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param fileId ID of the file to insert permission for.
   * @param value User or group e-mail address, domain name or {@code null}
                  "default" type.
   * @param type The value "user", "group", "domain" or "default".
   * @param role The value "owner", "writer" or "reader".
   * @return The inserted permission if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
   */
  private static Permission insertPermission(Drive service, String fileId,
      String value, String type, String role) {
    Permission newPermission = new Permission();

    newPermission.setValue(value);
    newPermission.setType(type);
    newPermission.setRole(role);
    try {
      return service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPermission).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    }
    return null;
  }

  // ...

}
```